# How to fix: 2 DIV with float left not working

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, multiple-columns

I have the main division: panel-body and divisions inside: package
My package display inside of panel-body proprely and they stack in row.

Here's the live website: https://royalkingdom.net/store/?cat=1

I've tried adding to my package: `float:left;` but when I do so, the packages don't go insied the body.

[image]

If I remove `float:left;` it works but they are not 3 per row

[image]

My package css:

```
.package {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

My panel-body css:

```
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: url(https://castiamc.com/buycraft/bordersv2/Middle.png);
    width: 850px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.panel-body {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align:justify;
}
.panel .panel-body {
    color: #3d3e3f;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 750px;
    top: -75px;
    left: 13px;
}
```

```
<div class="package">
<img src="'.(isset($image) && $image!="" && ($it == 1 || $it == 3 || $it == IMG_JPEG) ? $image : "img/404.jpg").'" class="img-rounded img-responsive" style="width:250px; height:168px;">
</div>
```

I'm looking to display 3 packages per row inside the panel-body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the parent of the packages, add an additional class called `clearfix` and define this class in your stylesheet:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Basically the floats take the elements out of the natural flow of the parent so adding this "forces" it back to its "normal" size.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand :/ So I use my 
```
.package {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
```
and add 
```
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```
and keep this in my html ?
```
<div class="package">
<img src="'.(isset($image) && $image!="" && ($it == 1 || $it == 3 || $it == IMG_JPEG) ? $image : "img/404.jpg").'" class="img-rounded img-responsive" style="width:250px; height:168px;">
</div>
```

Comment: You add `clearfix` class on the **parent** of the floats. Because you're adding an extra element that clears the floats (the `after`), the parent div will stretch to fit it.